# Twitter sign in script cannot import name Api

Tags: python

I am using the following code to sign in to twitter:

```
import simplejson
import twitter
import oauth
import oauthtwitter


from oauthtwitter import OAuthApi

class OauthRequest():
    CONSUMER_KEY = ""
    CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
    AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize'
    REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = 'https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token'

    def GetRequest(self):
        vOauthApi = OAuthApi(self.CONSUMER_KEY, self.CONSUMER_SECRET)
        self.mOauthRequestToken = vOauthApi.getRequestToken(self.REQUEST_TOKEN_URL)
        self.mOauthRequestUrl = vOauthApi.getAuthorizationURL(self.mOauthRequestToken)
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\twitter.py", line 4, in <module>
    import oauthtwitter
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\oauthtwitter.py", line 17, in <module>
    from twitter import Api, User
ImportError: cannot import name Api
```

I have installed PIP and downloaded the 'oauth', 'oauthtwitter' and 'twitter' modules using it. I am running Windows Vista and Python 3.3. As far as I can tell in my 'Lib' folder the files are there for oauthtwitter.

I'm noy sure exactly what is going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: The problem isn't that `oauthtwitter` is missing, it's that it's trying to import from `twitter` but the only one it finds does not contain `Api`. Or probably `User`. Let me guess, your script name is `twitter.py`? If not, what is the output of `print(twitter.__file__)` after line 2?

Comment: @WayneWerner yes my script is called twitter.py...should i name it something else?

Comment: probably - because it looks like `oauthtwitter` is importing *your* script, and not the `twitter` you have installed.

Comment: @waynewerner actually i have just renamed it and it has no effect on the outcome...i dont understand why it cant find api...there is a module called that within the folder containing the twitter scripts

Comment: @WayneWerner the result of print(twitter.__file__) is C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\twitter\__init__.py